# Is the comment area of a news story a distraction to the user?

Tags: user-behavior, comments, user-generated-content

i mean, include a area to comments in a news can make the reader forget the read content? as you know, Comment areas are full of conversations fleeing subject, hate speech,trolls and much more, so, it is dispensable? or not? you think the review adds value to the content of the news?

Answer (score 1):

**About reading comments**

The usual disposition of comments is the lower section, so to read them, you have to finish the article or go straight to read them.

If you have already finished the article, then the comments don't distract you from the article itself. They may distract your reasoning after the article, or your opinion, or even your mood, but that would be more biasing than distracting.

If you go straight to the comments, that means that what you wanted to read was people opinions about a subject, and not the article itself, then comments is your primary focus and we could even consider that the article could be distracting you from reading the comments.

**About writing comments**

If what you are reading generates a reaction on you, the reader, and want to comment on it, then there are two options, to comment immediately or to finish reading and then comment. If you wait to finish the article, then the existing comments and your own comment are not distracting you from reading. If you jump straight to the comments section, then you are your own distraction regarding the article, even if you write your comment and quickly go back up to finish the article.

I think that comments could be considered as "time suckers" since if you start reading them, they will take some time, not just to read them, but to calm down after that; but not a distraction.

Commenting, may be a distraction in the sense that a good comment should be useful, thoughtful, may be researched and should be well written; although most of the time that is not the case, so we can say that even commenting is not a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't see that like a distraction, for me, a distraction is something that disturb the user's reading.
Of course the fact to see other comments might influence his opinion, but I think that it's very important to leave to your users the possibility to comment, because even if there are trolls... it effectively adds a value because there are also some very interesting comments.
If you are worried about trolls comments and bad comments, you could let your users vote up and vote down for comments, if a comment have a negative note, you could lower his opacity (like on this website : http://www.mac4ever.com/actu/87843_une-veste-pour-apple-l-injonction-contre-samsung-est-refusee)

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is not germane to core content is, of course, a distraction. Comments are sometimes very germane (such as on this site) but as you are hinting at, on general news sites, the comments tend to have nothing to do with the content. In fact, I'd go as far to say that they often degrade the quality of the content.

But keep in mind that on media sites, comments aren't necessarily there to improve the user experience as much as they are there to in crease eyeballs and click-rates for advertising purposes.